Call to undefined relationship [product] on model [App\Models\Product] ...I try to solve it but I failed
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'location','price','discount_price','quantity','category','publish_status','image','image_two','image_three'];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'category','id');
    }

    public function product_two()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Product_two::class,'product_id','id');
    }

    public function product_plan(){
        return $this->hasOne(Product_plan::class, 'other_details','id');
    }

}

//my controllers function

public function show_product(){
$product=Product::with(['product.product_plan','product.product_two'])->get();
        return view('admin.show_product',compact('product'));
    }


product_plan model
class Product_plan extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['day_one','day_two','day_three','day_four','day_five','day_six','day_seven','day_eight','day_nine','day_ten','other_details'];
    

    public function product(){

        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'other_details','id');
    }

}

//product_twos model
class Product_two extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['duration','description','start_date','end_date','journey_date','expiry_date','provide','not_provide','extra_service','child_policy','seller_id','product_id'];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class,'product_id','id');
    }

}


You don't need to specify the current model with the relationship loader. Just use with(['product_plan','product_two'])

If I don’t specify relationship than it does not show all data at once.  If I try to load all data in blade file using foreach loop It show null

Error means what relationship are you calling does not exist in that model.
Controller.
public function show_product(){
$product=Product::with(['product_plan','product_two'])->get();
        return view('admin.show_product',compact('product'));
    }

